# How to whitelist an api path in FastAPI after adding API key for entire app?

Tags: fastapi

I have created an app as following:

```
X_API_KEY = APIKeyHeader(name='X-API-Key')

def validate_api_key(x_api_key: str = Depends(X_API_KEY)):
    if x_api_key == ENV_API_KEY:
        return True

    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Invalid API Key",
    )


app = FastAPI(
    title="My boring app",
    version=APP_VERSION,
    dependencies=[Security(validate_api_key)],
    root_path="/api/v1"
)

@app.get("/secretdata")
def secretdata() -> dict:
    return 'data'


@app.get("/")
    def is_alive() -> dict:
        return True
```

How can I whitelist the '/' path from security (api key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to split your application into multiple routers as shown in the example for [bigger applications in the FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter).

Here's an example fitting your case:

```py
# add import
from fastapi import APIRouter

X_API_KEY = APIKeyHeader(name='X-API-Key')

def validate_api_key(x_api_key: str = Depends(X_API_KEY)):
    if x_api_key == ENV_API_KEY:
        return True

    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Invalid API Key",
    )


app = FastAPI(
    title="My boring app",
    version=APP_VERSION,
    # removed global dependency
    root_path="/api/v1"
)

# generate new routers
protected_router = APIRouter()
unprotected_router = APIRouter()

# use respective router
@protected_router.get("/secretdata")
def secretdata() -> dict:
    return 'data'


@unprotected_router.get("/")
    def is_alive() -> dict:
        return True

# include the routers in the application, and add dependencies where needed
app.include_router(protected_router, dependencies=[Security(validate_api_key)]
# note: no dependency for this one
app.include_router(unprotected_router)
```

For this to be a bit cleaner you would usually split these routers into separate files, as shown in the previously mentioned documentation!